# C# NEST ElasticSearch search and highlight all fields in all types

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Im new to elastic-stack and want to implement global search on my indexed models and this is what I came up with at the moment:

```
        var response = _client.Search<IndexBase>(s => s
                                                     .Type(Types.Type(typeof(A), typeof(B)))
                                                     .Query(qry => qry
                                                                .Bool(b => b
                                                                          .Must(m => m
                                                                                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                                                                                                     .DefaultField("_all")
                                                                                                     .Query(request.Query)))))
                                                     .Highlight(h =>
                                                                    h.Fields(f => f.Field("_all")))
```

But no highlights is showing up in my hits for documents. What Im doing wrong? How I can retrieve [index, count] pairs for highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing "_all" in the highlighter with *

```
     var response = _client.Search<IndexBase>(s => s
                                                 .Type(Types.Type(typeof(A), typeof(B)))
                                                 .Query(qry => qry
                                                            .Bool(b => b
                                                                      .Must(m => m
                                                                                .QueryString(qs => qs
                                                                                                 .DefaultField("_all")
                                                                                                 .Query(request.Query)))))
                                                 .Highlight(h =>
                                                                h.Fields(f => f.Field("*")))
```

Comment: I think your answer is what he is looking for, but I would suggest for everyone to look into why this is not working as well because this can cause performance or strange results.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, though, I don't quite understand why.

Comment: It may be dependent upon which version of Elastic that you're using, but I can tell you that the "*" portion for the highlighter field will run against each field rather than just the "_all" field because it is a wildcard selector that will choose every field.

Answer (score 0):

You are not indexing the fields properly.

In order to perform highlighting, the actual content of the field is required. If the field in question is stored (has store set to true in the mapping) it will be used, otherwise, the actual _source will be loaded and the relevant field will be extracted from it.

The _all field cannot be extracted from _source, so it can only be used for highlighting if it mapped to have store set to true.
[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html)

Also for any bigger set of data this can cause a performance drop so it's always better to set the search fields in the proper way and know what you are trying to highlight.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I would like to search among fields just because I want scattered search across all types and don't really mind which field used, so it is by design for simplicity of code and logic when users search something - I can just show geterogenous list of indexed documents, and dynamicaly highlight any field I want.